# Issue with pure-CSS fancy checkbox

Tags: css

I am trying to come up with a pure-css fancy checkbox. And I have succeeded to achieve my goal by 90%, with the only exception that I see the irritating standard chechbox appear from under my fancy checkbox. And I can't get rid of it. Any help ?

```css
.checkboxFive {
  width: 12px;
  margin: 12px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkboxFive label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkboxFive label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkboxFive label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.checkboxFive input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFiveInput" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove it from screen with `position` and coordonates.

*(`display` or `visibility` might become an accessibility issue)*

```css
.checkboxFive {
  width: 12px;
  margin: 12px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkboxFive label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkboxFive label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkboxFive label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#checkboxFiveInput {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
}
.checkboxFive input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFiveInput" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `display:none` to checkboxFiveInput.

```css
.checkboxFive {
  width: 12px;
  margin: 12px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkboxFive input {
   display:none;
 }

.checkboxFive label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkboxFive label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkboxFive label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.checkboxFive input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFiveInput" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. @Namoz, one more question (off-topic). How do you change the color of the tick ?

Comment: On .checkboxFive label:after change the following line : border: 3px solid blue;
 Blue is the color of the tick, you can use hexa value.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in creating a custom checkbox is to add `visibility: hidden` to your `input` element.  In your case, your css would look like this:

```
.checkboxFive #checkboxFiveInput {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can see this [link](https://paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css) for more information about building custom checkboxes.